# Rest Client - Can i set connectionPoolSize?

Tags: resteasy, quarkus, microprofile, quarkus-rest-client

Microprofile allows to define connectionPoolSize from RestClient like this:

`io.smallrye.restclient.tests.proxy.HelloClient/property/resteasy.connectionPoolSize = 4`

When I set this property in my project, quarkus ignores it. How can i define it?

Answer (score 1):

If your configured client is @RegisterRestClient(configKey="myClient"), to set the pool size use:

```
quarkus.rest-client.myClient.connection-pool-size: 5
```

(...and not myClient/mp-rest/connectionPoolSize)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create class **MyRestClientBuilderListener** implements **RestClientBuilderListener**:

`package org.myproject.config`

```
public class MyRestClientBuilderListener implements RestClientBuilderListener {
    
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MgiRestClientBuilderListener.class);
    static final String CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE_PROP = "config.restclient.connectionPoolSize";

    @Override
    public void onNewBuilder(RestClientBuilder builder) {
        Config cfg = ConfigProvider.getConfig();
        Integer poolSizeConnection = cfg.getValue(CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE_PROP, Integer.class);
        
        if(poolSizeConnection == null) {
            poolSizeConnection = 50;//default
        }

        builder.property("resteasy.connectionPoolSize", poolSizeConnection);
    }
}
```

2. Create file with name **org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.spi.RestClientBuilderListener** in **META-INF\services** with content:

`org.myproject.config.MyRestClientBuilderListener`

Comment: I have several clients. Anyway to distinguish them?